# Add a horizontal line after last line on each page in longtable

Tags: longtable

When the long tables in my book reaches the end of a page, the vertical lines with no hline look very unappealing. Can longtable add an hline or maybe a thinner line at each pagebreak?

[image: Two pages in the book]

Answer (score 4):

use

```
\hline
\endfoot
```

at the start of the table so it adds a line at the bottom of each page.

Comment: That easy?!!  This has been giving me dyspepsia for weeks and I never thought to ask! :O The horror!!!