# How put a header in every last line of a longtable

Tags: longtable

I'm working with `longtable` and I'd like to know how to automatically put a header in every last line of a table, before the page turns (a header like the "endhead" command does).

```
\caption{Grande Tabela}
\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrr}
\toprule
\toprule
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\

111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
\bottomrule
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}%





\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know `\firstfoot` and `\endfoot`? See the documentation of longtable (type `texdoc longtable` in your terminal/console) for more information please.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code fragment to small but complete document (minimal working example: mwe) with your table, hat we can copy it and compile in our computers as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following MWE. There I added the two commands `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot`. Before them you can define the content of the footer for your used table. Because I do not know what you want to add there I only used text `endfoot` and `endlastfoot`. See the used rules too in the code.

MWE (important changes marked with `<=========`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrr}
\caption{Grande Tabela}\label{tab:granTable}\\ % <======================
  \toprule
  \toprule
  111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
  \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Grande Tabela (cont.)} \\ % <==================================
  \toprule
  \toprule
  111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
  \midrule
\endhead
  \bottomrule
  endfoot
\endfoot % <============================================================
  \bottomrule
  \bottomrule
  endlastfoot
\endlastfoot % <========================================================
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111   & 111 \\
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please read the documentation of `longtable` with typing `texdoc longtable` in your terminal/console!

Comment: @GabrielBento Are you looking for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334608/36296 ?